# Where should I call the json_read function that prints out data as a .json format? - Python

Tags: python, json, callback, type-conversion, handshake

I have this function that sniffs packets in a constant loop using pcap library in Python.

```
def interface_listening(interface):
    try:
        packets = pcap.pcap(name=interface)
    except OSError as exception:
        print('[-] Issue: {0}'.format(exception))
        sys.exit(-1)
    while True:
        print('[+] Listening on interface {0}'.format(packets.name))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        packets.loop(0, ethernet_parse) #constant loop
```

The prototype of `packets.loop` is that it takes a callback function, in this case : `ethernet_parse`.

I do some parsing of the packets order by order , which means: Ethernet,Ip,Tcp until I arrive at TLS information. The goal is to extract some `Client Hello` information and output the data as a `.json` format.

The parsing of Client Hello is done like this:

```
def parse_client_hello(handshake):
    if isinstance(handshake.data, dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello):
        client = dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello(str(handshake.data))
        HANDSHAKE['Client_Hello']['Version'] = tls_dictionary('tls_version',client.version)
        session_id, pointer = parse(client.data, 1)
        HANDSHAKE['Client_Hello']['Session ID'] = hexlify(session_id)
        ciphersuites, pointer1 = parse(client.data[pointer:], 2)
        ciphersuites, pretty_cipher_suites = parse_extension(ciphersuites, 'cipher_suites')
        HANDSHAKE['Client_Hello']['Cipher Suites'] = pretty_cipher_suites
        HANDSHAKE['Client_Hello']['Random'] = client.random
        pointer += pointer1 
        compression_methods, pointer1 = parse(client.data[pointer:], 1)
        compression_methods, pretty_compressions = parse_extension(compression_methods,
            'compression_methods')
        HANDSHAKE['Client_Hello']['Compression Method'] = pretty_compressions
```

HANDSHAKE is a dictionary that I used in order to print the data as a .json format.

```
HANDSHAKE = {
    "Client_Hello" : {
        'Handshake Type': 'unknown',
        'Length': 'unknown',
        'Version': 'unknown',
        'Random': 'unknown',
        'Session ID': 'unknown',
        'Session ID Length': 'unknown',
        'Cipher Suites': 'unknown',
        'Compression Method': 'unknown'
        }
}
```

My goal is to fill out this dictionary with the captured data in `parse_client_hello` function for each packet, and to use the `json_read function` in order to have a file that contains all the captured data of `"Client Hello"` printed as a .json format.

```
def json_read(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as f:
    json.dump(HANDSHAKE, f)
```

**My question is:** Where should I call the `json_read function`? If I call it just right after `packets.loop` of `interface_listening` function, it is never called.

I would be really grateful if you could answer this.